# Drawing Circle/SemiCircle in Metal

Tags: metal, metalkit

I am new to metal. I want to draw a semi circle. Any ideas or suggestions to draw a semi circle. I tried using tesselation

```
float u = patch_coord.x;
float v = patch_coord.y;
float w = patch_coord.z;




   float x = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.x + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.x + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.x;
    float y = u * patchIn.control_points[0].position.y + v * patchIn.control_points[1].position.y + w * patchIn.control_points[2].position.y;

    float2 tangent = normalize(float2(x, y)) / 25;
```

When I normalize always it is in the middle of the screen. I want to draw circle in my finger touch.